# JavaScript error when trying to build a hide/show feature into a dygraph (from an R markdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, r-markdown, dygraphs

I'm creating a dygraph using this:

```
 library(dygraphs)
    library(htmlwidgets)
    library(rgl)
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    knitr::knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
    includeScript('C://Desktop//Javascripts/dygraph.js')
    includeScript('C://Desktop//Javascripts/jquery-3.6.0.js')
    
    df<-data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("1980-03-01), length.out = 100, by="day), Long = rnorm(100,50,10), Medium = rnorm(100,30, 5), Short = rnorm(100,10,2), Very.Short = rnorm(100,5,1))
        
    dygraph(df, elementId="the_plot") %>% dyAxis("y", label= "Value ($s)") %>% dyOptions(labelsUTC = TRUE) %>% dyCrosshair(direction = "vertical") %>% dyHighlight(highlightCircleSize = 5, highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha = 0.2, hideOnMouseOut = FALSE) %>% dyCallbacks(drawCallback = JS('
  function(dygraph, is_initial) {
    if (!is_initial) return;

    var data = this.dataHandler_.data_;
    var labels = dygraph.getLabels();
    var num_cols = labels.length - 1; // exclude x-axis
    var checkboxes_html = "";

    // generate checkbox HTML for each series
    for (var i = 1; i <= num_cols; i++) {
      var label = labels[i];
      var id = "checkbox" + i;
      checkboxes_html += "<label><input type=\\"checkbox\\" id=\\"" + id + "\\" checked> " + label + "</label><br>";
    }

    // add checkboxes to the page
    $("#checkboxes").html(checkboxes_html);

    // add change event listeners to checkboxes
    $("#checkboxes").find("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
      var series = this.id.replace("checkbox", "");
      var show = this.checked;
      dygraph.setVisibility(parseInt(series), show);
    });
  }'))
```

I'm trying to add some checkboxes that'll allow users of the knitted markdown html to show and hide individual series on that dygraph. While I can get it to knit to an html fine, I can't get the checkboxes to render.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure what is `the_plot` . But , if it is id selector as i am seeing in your code i,e : `elementId="the_plot"` then you need to use `$("#the_plot")..` instead of just `the_plot` in your jquery code.

Comment: alec22 - a couple of your comment replies are "it doesn't work". We often say here that "doesn't work" is the least helpful fault report possible, since it gives your interlocutor nothing new to go on, and they have to ask you follow-up questions to elucidate on what you are seeing. If you can explain, in each case, _how_ it doesn't work - with as much detail as possible - that is often a more productive approach.

Comment: Apologies, I was trying to highlight that it doesn't change from my original issue - the boxes still don't render within the markdown or on the html.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
library(dygraphs)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(rgl)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
includeScript('C://Desktop//Javascripts/dygraph.js')
includeScript('C://Desktop//Javascripts/jquery-3.6.0.js')

df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("1980-03-01"), length.out = 100, by="day"), 
                 Long = rnorm(100,50,10), 
                 Medium = rnorm(100,30, 5), 
                 Short = rnorm(100,10,2), 
                 Very.Short = rnorm(100,5,1))

dygraph(df, elementId="the_plot") %>% 
  dyAxis("y", label= "Value ($s)") %>% 
  dyOptions(labelsUTC = TRUE) %>% 
  dyCrosshair(direction = "vertical") %>% 
 dyHighlight(highlightCircleSize = 5, 
highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha = 0.2, 
hideOnMouseOut = FALSE) %>%
dyCallbacks(drawCallback = JS('
  function(dygraph, is_initial) {
    if (!is_initial) return;

    var data = dygraph.rawData();
    var labels = dygraph.getLabels();
    var num_cols = labels.length - 1; // exclude x-axis
    var checkboxes_html = "";

    // generate checkbox HTML for each series
    for (var i = 1; i <= num_cols; i++) {
      var label = labels[i];
      var id = "checkbox" + i;
      checkboxes_html += "<label><input type=\\"checkbox\\" id=\\"" + id + "\\" checked> " + label + "</label><br>";
    }

    // add checkboxes to the page
    $("#checkboxes").html(checkboxes_html);

    // add change event listeners to checkboxes
    $("#checkboxes").find("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
      var series = this.id.replace("checkbox", "");
      var show = this.checked;
      dygraph.setVisibility(parseInt(series), show);
    });
  }
'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sadly adding this also doesn't achieve the objective

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work, you could try and create a plugin for it like here: https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-plugins.html

```
import * as utils from './dygraph-utils';
import DygraphInteraction from './dygraph-interaction-model';
import IFrameTarp from './iframe-tarp';

const SeriesToggle = (function() {

  "use strict";

  /**
   * @constructor
   */
  const SeriesToggle = function() {
    this.checkboxContainer_ = null;
    this.dygraph_ = null;
    this.labels_ = null;
  };

  SeriesToggle.prototype.toString = function() {
    return 'SeriesToggle Plugin';
  };

  SeriesToggle.prototype.activate = function(dygraph) {
    this.dygraph_ = dygraph;
    this.labels_ = dygraph.getLabels();
    return {
      layout: this.layout
    };
  };

  SeriesToggle.prototype.layout = function(e) {
    if (this.checkboxContainer_ === null) {
      this.createCheckboxes_();
    }
    this.positionCheckboxes_();
  };

  SeriesToggle.prototype.createCheckboxes_ = function() {
    const containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    containerDiv.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;';
    this.checkboxContainer_ = containerDiv;

    const labels = this.labels_;
    for (let i = 1; i < labels.length; i++) {
      const label = labels[i];
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = 'checkbox';
      input.checked = true;
      input.onclick = this.checkboxClickHandler_(label);
      containerDiv.appendChild(input);

      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = label;
      containerDiv.appendChild(span);
    }
    this.dygraph_.graphDiv.appendChild(containerDiv);
  };

  SeriesToggle.prototype.positionCheckboxes_ = function() {
    const area = this.dygraph_.getArea();
    const containerDiv = this.checkboxContainer_;
    containerDiv.style.left = area.x + 'px';
    containerDiv.style.width = area.w + 'px';
  };

  SeriesToggle.prototype.checkboxClickHandler_ = function(label) {
    const self = this;
    return function(e) {
      self.dygraph_.setVisibility(label, e.target.checked);
    };
  };

  return SeriesToggle;

})();

Dygraph.Plugins.SeriesToggle = SeriesToggle;
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work on my end